# Find numeric record number in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been using this site for longer than I can remember, but I've never had to ask a question before - I've always been able to find what I need - but this one could use some SQL expertise for the best approach since it's kind of a worst case.

I have a text comment field that gets a lot of stuff put in it in no consistent format - it'll include a patient name, hopefully a record ID (which could come from 2 different tables differentiated by the range), spaces, slashes, phone numbers, the initials of whoever entered it, etc.  I'll scrub some examples...  I need to find the numeric RecordID in here (it references another disconnected system) and ignore the rest.  There's a remote possibility it could have 2 record numbers (could be referenced in two different tables) - if so, I need to pick the more important one.

Example Data (scrubbed):
Sanchez, Raul - POS - OS - 489-849-7894 - AB - Conf >> Nothing of value here/return NULL
Smith, Nancy RL 1458968-rl >> Return 1458968
Sudhu, Mandeep intake # 78596/rl >> Return 78596
1887569 Smith, Jonathan-ESK >> Return 1021015
Montana, Joe/1451252rm >> Return 1451252
Johnson, Fredy/1784569/78563/RG >> Return 1784569

My first thought was to do a bunch of nested Replace() functions to turn anything that's not a character into a standard delimiter, parse these all into separate records with split_string(), then only pick the largest number - and that would work in every instance except #5 above... but is that the best way, or is there something better? SQL Version is 2017 for reference to available functions.

This will be wrapped into a scalar valued function.

Thanks!

Comment: Do your identifiers have any formatting rules? Min/max length?

Comment: They're typical autonumber fields in a related database so we can definitely figure out the range they'll be in for the foreseeable future.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: This is a bit of a cop-out suggestion buy you may need to investigate creating a user defined function. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/february/sql-server-regular-expressions-for-efficient-sql-querying you can create a C# function to give yourself full access to a "real" regex system. If that works you regex could be as simple as /[0-9]{5-7}/ or whatever matches your format.

Comment: Interesting return `1887569 Smith, Jonathan-ESK >> Return 1021015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to extract all numbers.

t1 identify all non-digit characters in each text.
t2 replaces all non-digit characters with spaces.
t3 assumes that numbers might be separated by an unknown number of spaces, and replaces every sequence of spaces with a single space.

Enjoy :-)

```
with
t1 
as 
(
    select  record_id
           ,txt
           ,trim(translate(txt, '1234567890', space(10))) as non_digits 
    from    t
),
t2 
as 
(  
    select  record_id
           ,trim(translate(txt, non_digits, space(len(non_digits)))) as spaced_numberes 
    from    t1
),
t3 
as 
(
    select  record_id
           ,replace(replace(replace(spaced_numberes, ' ', ' *'), '* ', ''), '*', '') as space_delimited_numbers 
           
    from    t2
)
select  t3.record_id
       ,ss.value  
       
from    t3 
        cross apply string_split(space_delimited_numbers, ' ') as ss
```

| record_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 489 |
| 1 | 849 |
| 1 | 7894 |
| 2 | 1458968 |
| 3 | 78596 |
| 4 | 1887569 |
| 5 | 1451252 |
| 6 | 1784569 |
| 6 | 78563 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7ac70637ccc6709a2935078f8b696e42)

Comment: This is a neat example that I'm trying out in the form of a function.  I did notice that if the string has a number as the last character, it kills the 3rd CTE so as a lazy way I'm just adding a string character to the end of all input values just to be safe.

Comment: See updated answer. The issue was actually in the 2nd CTE, caused by an edge case for the 1st CTE.  in case the non-digits are spaces only (E.g. for '111 222 333'), the length of the non-digits string is 0 (len() does not count trailing spaces). This broke the translate() that requires equal-length strings for the 2nd & 3rd parameters. Fixed by adding trim() to the 1st CTE

Comment: Even better - thx... I'll update my function to include that.  I'm very grateful for the help - the results are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to extract the first number using some MS SQL pattern-matching:

- detect the position of the first digit for the first number, using [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- detect the position of the last digit for the first number, using [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- extract the number using [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT string,
       SUBSTRING(string,
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]%'      , string), 
                 1+PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', string)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',string))
FROM tab
```

Once you have this, you could do some cross checks on these numbers.

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae5e50702543c1ba3d170859c47cb4d2).

**Note**: this solution assumes that your interesting value, if any, is found as first number, condition tweakable with a better pattern matching given the domain of your values.

Does it help for your case?

Comment: wow I appreciate the time you put into this example.  I played with it a bit but struggled a little with the best way to account for multiple numbers within the string and getting the best one out.   I haven't abandoned this yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to upvote - that's funny!  Not sure how to make sure I give proper credit and still leave this open to further critique so let me know if I need to do something...
Anyway I took David's suggestion and turned it into this:

```
DECLARE @String as varchar(255)
SET @String = 'Montana, Joe/14510252rm/8456,71253|'
;
WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT @String AS String) T
)
, cte2 AS
(
    SELECT String, translate(string, '1234567890', space(10)) AS non_digits
    FROM cte1
)
, cte3 AS 
(  
    SELECT  string, non_digits
           ,trim(translate(String, non_digits, space(len(non_digits)))) as spaced_numbers 
    FROM    cte2
)
, cte4 AS
(
    SELECT string, replace(replace(replace(spaced_numbers, ' ', ' *'), '* ', ''), '*', '') as space_delimited_numbers 
    FROM cte3
)
, cte5 AS
(
    SELECT string , cast(ss.value as int) result
    FROM cte4
    CROSS APPLY string_split(space_delimited_numbers,' ') as ss
)
SELECT TOP 1 result
FROM cte5
WHERE (result between 1000000 AND 2000000)  OR (result between 70000 AND 199999) ORDER BY result DESC
```